# Make MySQL Index Specific To Attempted Entered Value in 2 Fields

Tags: mysql, indexing

Let's say I have a table with fields:

```
id|name|value
```

I'd like to create an index that prevents entries of records where value > 0 when name == 'Bob' for example. Does MySQL have any native functionality like this or does it need to be programmed into my application logic?

Comment: I think you can do it with a trigger.

Comment: This is actually something that should be done through a check constraint not an index - but MySQL does not support this. It also does not support conditional indexes. So the only workaround you have is to use a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to program it, and mainly that is the better approach also, since you dont want you database to validate you queries. Just to run you queries.